# Scientific basis to assume consciousness could survive if your body matter was disintegrated, then "magically" reconstituted?

Tags: magic, science-fiction, consciousness

Lets assume that some mechanism, magical or scientific, existed such that an individual could be vaporized, i.e, every atom in the body separated by some larger-than-normal distance from every other atom that makes up that body.

Now assume another mechanism, magical or scientific, existed such that all of those atoms could be collected and arranged back in their exact positions, ie, every neuron and neuron connection back the way it was. Is there any scientific basis to assume that the original consciousness survives? Is the resulting individual simply a *perfect* clone? Can a meaningful distinction between the consciousness that existed before the disintegration and after the reconstitution even be made?

Comment: Not an answer, just saying that your suggested process of disintegration/ rebuilding is the basis of teleportation. And the question you've posed is a commonly asked one by people contemplating teleportation, too.

Comment: You are talking about a thing called resurrection. The body disappears, but the spirit survives, when the body is brought back to life it's knit back with its spirit.

Comment: To call this process *cloning* is misleading. The resulting individual may be a perfect *copy*. If so, making meaningful distinctions about their consciousness may be nigh on impossible.

Comment: Hello and welcome to worldbuilding. This question is off-topic for this forum and — as the answering parties have pointed out — most likely suited for the Philosophy SE. Please take some time to visit [WB SE's nifty help-center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) for excellent tips on how to write questions for this forum, the likes of which I am sure you will soon provide many. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question you ask is *very* old, and has never been fully answered to the satisfaction of the philosophical community.  Many answers have been put forth, so you can pick the answer you like, and then look up the arguments for it.

The key to such a disintegration and reintegration process is to *define* consciousness.  If it supervenes on matter, meaning it's entirely defined by the rules of how matter operates, and you put the matter back together in exactly the same way, then consciousness will survive.  On the other hand, if consciousness is indeed something metaphysical, then the question would be how would one coax the consciousness back to inhabit the body.

The most common answer I have seen is that it cannot be done, but the reasons differ, and the arguments are always tenuous.

The oldest challenge I know of for this is that of the [Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus).  It's an exercise in how much you can replace of an original thing and retain its identity.  The Ship of Theseus is an old ship.  It's so old that, over time, every single board that made up the ship when it was christened has been replaced.  Is it still the Ship of Theseus, even though it doesn't share a single common atom?  If not, when did it cease to be the Ship of Theseus.

The most powerful challenge I have seen is one associated with teleportation.  You have a system where one scans the body destructively, and then transmits that information to reconstitute it somewhere else.  You teleport from Earth to Mars, but due to a mishap, the information is also sent to Venus.  Both Mars and Venus stations reconstitute your body perfectly.  Which one is the "real" you?

The answers to these questions are very deep, so don't expect the answers to be obvious.  However, they are key to answering your question, so consider them with care!

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into the other arguments, but I think that the scenario that consciousness supervenes on matter is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If one takes a materialist view of this teleportation process, then consciousness of an individual is merely (merely!) the product of the structure of their body and all its constituent parts. Creating an exact or a perfect copy of the individual when create someone with the same consciousness of the disintegrated individual. Structure has been destroyed in one place and reconstituted at another. Distance will have little to do with it except for the practical aspects in transmitting the information from one place to another.

While science isn't exclusively materialist in its worldview, it does tend to exclude entities which it has no evidence for their physical existence. In this sense consciousness lacks any physical properties. It is better thought of as the emergent properties of organisms with complex neurological systems. Therefore, if you can reconstitute an individual that is an organism with a complex neurological system it will have the same emergent properties as its original, and should have the same consciousness.

Of course, if the process of creating *perfect* copies could be carried out without disintegrating the original individual, then this would multiply the number of individuals with the same consciousness. If any differences in their consciousness existed, they are quite likely to be indistinguishable.

The alternative conceptualization is the Cartesian model where consciousness is intangible *something* that exists outside the body. presumably, this extrinsic consciousness could readily reunite itself with the reconstituted individual. Unless, of course, the disintegration process permanently severed any connection with the structure that was the individual. However, there is no scientific basis for the existence of spirit-like consciousness, this is wholly a philosophical construct due to [Rene Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes), and this place its consideration outside the ambit of this question.

In summary, if consciousness is an emergent property of complex organisms then their disintegration and reconstitution should recreate individuals with the same consciousness of their disintegrated original. Consideration of the [mind-body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind%E2%80%93body_problem) is without a scientific basis and therefore outside the scope of this question (an this answer too).

Answer (score -1):

If you could get all the neuron action potentials right and all the transmitter levels across every synapse perfectly set the way they were pre-disintegration then the poor unfortunate you shredded wouldn't even notice they were gone. But here's the fun thing; even if the copy has the very soul of the original what you have in fact created is a new person who thinks they're the original, the original is still dead. People who understand this tend to shy away from being resurrected for this reason.